# How to execute a Java app with arguments in c#

Tags: c#, java, command, arguments

I have researched and attempted to do this myself, but with no luck. I am trying to execute a java app and pass it a few variables. It is finding the java and running it, but not passing it any variables, here is what I have so far -

```
Process proc = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.Arguments = @"-jar javaapp.jar" + "host:port" +     "password" + "/say" + "test";
        startInfo.FileName = "java";
        proc.StartInfo = startInfo;
        proc.Start();
```

I cant work this out at all. I dont want to use any third party software (unless it can be packaged in the .EXE) as this is meant to be distributed to people who need it. Any help is thanked.

Comment: Have you tried to insert spaces while concatinating *startInfo.Arguments*  string (like `@"-jar javaapp.jar[space]"`) ? Better output `startInfo.Argument` for debugging and see what you get.

Comment: @L.B I havent tried doing that, but I think the issue is that the arguments are being applied to the java.exe, and not the app itself.

Comment: then try, before making assumptions..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put spaces in the strings you're concatenating, your command currently looks like

```
java -jar javaapp.jarhost:portpassword/saytest
```

The simplest way is to use `string.Format`:

```
string command1 = "/say"
string command2 = "test"
string args = string.Format("-jar javaapp.jar {0}:{1} {2} {3} {4}", host, port, password, command1, command2);
startInfo.Arguments = args;
```

Comment: The order for the arguments is <host:port> <pass> <command1> <command2>, they are in the wrong order in here and I dont understand this well enough to fix it.

Comment: @therimmer96 So you say you are unable just to fix the order?

Comment: @therimmer96 - I've updated the answer. You can use string concatenation instead of `string.Format`, although the problem appears to be you are not separating arguments with spaces in your argument string. You could write a small test application which prints its arguments and call that to see how the arguments are being passed from your code.

Comment: @L.B I was, as I have only recently started to learn C# and the ":" in it was throwing me off and making me confused. Now he has changed it I understand it much better. But it still does not pass the arguments to the java. It opens the window, but it closes quickly afterwards

Comment: @Lee Okay, it is now working, I just realised the command1 I had set was not a valid one, this problem is now solved

Answer (score 0):

Arguments is a string - the way you have it they'll all be mashed together with no space separating them.

The @ symbol in C# is used for literal format of string; it looks like you're trying to use it to build an array or something.